# chartjs stepSize by 5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I want my y-axes to raise by 5 ( for exampel 5,10,15) and so on. Instead of how it currently works, by 10, which is by default (10,20,30). How can i change this. I tried using the stepSize propertie but nothing happends.

[image]

This is my 'option' data on my chart object

```
{
scales: {
yAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    color: Charts.colors.gray[700],
    zeroLineColor: Charts.colors.gray[700]
  },
  ticks: {
    suggestedMin: 0, 
    suggestedMax:15,
    stepSize: 5,
    beginAtZero: true
}
}]
}
}
```

Comment: try to change `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` with `min` and `max`

Comment: i have tried this already with no luck @michal.jakubeczy

Answer (score 0):

stepSize should work as seen in this example with a forced stepsize of 1: (https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/zk4x0pun/2/).

```
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        suggestedMin: 0, 
        suggestedMax:15,
        stepSize: 1,
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
```

Can you check the version that you are using because maby it was a bug in an old version. Latest stable version is 2.9.4

Comment: iam using chart.js 2.9.4 :/

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your case in your post because your options look right from what you posted

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late :) but you can use this.

```
 yAxes: [
  {
    ticks: {
      callback: function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value).toFixed(0);
      },
      autoSkip: true,
      maxTicksLimit: 10,
      stepSize: .2
    }
  }
]
```